# How to redirect http and non http *.com to *.de via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I bought some webspace with 2 domains: com and de

I can access both domains with or without http:// respectively www

To prevent duplicate content I want to redirect ALL domains to just one domain, because they offer exact the same content in the same language.

So:
http:// www. example.com, http:// example.com and http:// example.de shall be redirected to www.example.de.

Is this possible with .htaccess and will this prevent duplicate content?

Comment: Better to set redirection in vhost config.

Comment: This can also be done just with **forwarding in your DNS** settings without touching .htaccess.

Comment: But will it prevent being "duplicate content" ?